# mysql-workbench on linux

Tags: mysql-workbench

I have a linux mint 17.2 and it seems that mysql-workbench is uninstallable.

```
E: Package 'mysql-workbench' has no installation candidate
[~]$ sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench-community
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-workbench-community : Depends: libctemplate2 but it is not installable
                             Depends: libgeos-c1 (>= 3.4.2) but it is not installable
                             Depends: libhdf4-0-alt but it is not installable
                             Depends: libhdf5-7 but it is not installable
                             Depends: libnetcdfc7 but it is not installable
                             Depends: libtinyxml2.6.2 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any ideas how to install it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately we don't suport Linux Mint. However you can build Workbench from source, see [this guide](http://mysqlworkbench.org/2011/10/1221/) for details.

Comment: Thank you. For now I'm using DBeaver which just works out of the box on linux, but in case I'll need the full workbench I'll definitely take a look at this guide.

Comment: Can't Linux Mint use Ubuntu packages?

Comment: Good point Philip Olson - Ubuntu packages shoud work on Mint, but no guarantee. You can try @AssafShomer

Comment: Hi Phillip. Usually Ubuntu packages work. There is something special going on with this one. I would be surprised if Mint is the problem, but haven't tried installing on vanilla Ubuntu.